# memory game in javascript

Tags: java, arrays, loops, memory

I am trying to make a memory game for my assignment in `Java`. I am stuck, so I need some help. So, I have made a menu where you choose your game difficulty (easy, medium, and hard). The various game modes give the player a different number of tries. I am stuck because I do not know how to get the tries' count to loop, making the count of tries go lower as the user guesses wrong. Moreover, I do not know how to flip the cards to show a certain letter (there is no code for this yet). Now, I have the game sets up as '[--]' to mimic the card being flipped over. If you can give me tips on the algorithm to make the count of tries, that would be great!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MemoryGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Welcome to Single Memory Game!\n");
    System.out.println("Please choose a diffictulty:");
    System.out.println("1 - Easy\n2 - Medium\n3 - Hard\n0 - Exit ");

    System.out.println(">> ");
    int Option = in.nextInt();

    if (Option == 1)
    {
        Scanner cardGuess = new Scanner (System.in);
        int Guesses = 20;
        System.out.println("You have "+ Guesses + " guesses remaining!");
        System.out.println("Please select card one: ");
        int cardOne = cardGuess.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please select card two: ");
        int cardTwo = cardGuess.nextInt();
    }
    else if (Option == 2)
    {
        Scanner cardGuess = new Scanner (System.in);
        int Guesses = 10;
        System.out.println("You have " + Guesses + " guesses remaining!");
        System.out.println("Please select card one: ");
        int cardOne = cardGuess.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please select card two: ");
        int cardTwo = cardGuess.nextInt();
    }
    else if (Option == 3)
    {
        Scanner cardGuess = new Scanner (System.in);
        int Guesses = 5;
        System.out.println("You have " + Guesses + " guesses remaining!");
        System.out.println("Please select card one: ");
        int cardOne = cardGuess.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please select card two: ");
        int cardTwo = cardGuess.nextInt();
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
    int[] randomNumbers; 
       randomNumbers = new int[11]; //All 19 cards 

       for(int index = 0; index < 11; index++) //Makes 9 indexes in the array
       {
           randomNumbers[index] = (int)(Math.random()*10); //Gives random values to index       
       }
       for(int index = 1; index < 11; index++)
       {
           randomNumbers[index] += randomNumbers[index-1];
       }

       for(int index = 0; index < 11; index++)
       {
           System.out.printf("[%3d] = [--]\n",index,randomNumbers[index]);
       }
}
}
```

Comment: `Java` != `JavaScript`

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you to use is an `ArrayList`(Easy to handle) and shuffle it(get rid of random stuff).

```
ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList();

for(int i = 0; i < numOfCards; ++i)
 list.add((char) (i + 'a'));

System.out.println("Before shuffle : " + list);

Collections.shuffle(list);

System.out.println("After shuffle : " + list);
```

In this way you can shuffle the whole arrayList everytime and get different array everytime.

```
Before shuffle : [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z]
After shuffle : [z, m, s, t, j, o, v, b, u, q, f, n, x, w, k, c, e, y, i, d, r, h, g, l, p, a]
```